# macOS project failing on runtime

Tags: xcode9, xcode9.2

So I have an xcode project that fails every time I run it on my computer. Works on other computers though. I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Swift/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
```

Now, when I look in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Swift/` I can't find the `libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib` file. But other swift projects work just fine. I have no idea how to fix this. I've tried cleaning, restarting my computer, creating a copy of the project, updating Xcode, updating command line tools, everything I could think of.

The project was working just fine a few hours ago. Something went wrong by itself. No clue how to fix things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending 6 straight hours debugging and trying to fix things, I found the solution. For some reason, my "Library Search Paths" was filled with the wrong directory. I never set it to that directory. But it was set.

Here is what I mean:

[image: LSP]

The highlighted field was filled with the following: `macosx/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Swift`

I just took that out. I hope this helps save some future traveler the pain and torture I went through

Comment: Thank you!! This saved me potentially a ton of digging around. Just to add another data point, I also was getting this under Xcode 9.2. My project was working fine for several days of development, then suddenly started crashing with this error—like you, I decidedly never changed the Library Search Paths, but it seems something triggered Xcode to change it for me. I'll file a radar.

Comment: This makes me really happy! This is literally the worst bug I have ever faced in my life. Glad I could spare someone from having to deal with the same.